# Do I buy a game twice if I bought it from humblebundle.com?

Tags: software-center, games

I bought a series of games on humblebundle.com, and I decided to install them on ubuntu software center. I am wondering if I also paid for the games on software center, since it said 'loading payment service.'

Does anyone know wether I bought the game twice or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the game costs 0.00?that would still say 'loading payment service'

Answer (score 2):

No, you are only paying once through [humblebundle.com](http://humblebundle.com).

From the *'Download your Humble Bundle'* page after choosing to download for Ubuntu:

> **Notes:** As these games have been recently added to Ubuntu Software Center it might take a minute for them to appear. If you see a *"Not found"* message, Ubuntu Software Center is working in the background to update the list of available apps.
>
> To install the app once Ubuntu Software Center has opened click on the *"Buy..."* button, **don't worry you won't be charged for it**.
>
> Also if your bundle included Psychonauts and it does not appear here it will be available shortly, please check back soon.

Answer (score 1):

No, I believe that once you click "buy" it checks your account, see's that you have already purchased the Humble Bundle and then begins the download.

Hope this helps,